# Where is Dr. Bashir from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Dr. Bashir clearly has an English accent (and his father has a distinct Cockney accent), but do we hear in canon and/or EU material where on Earth he comes from? (Picard has an English accent but is French, so there's only so much we can draw from accents).

Comment: We don’t even know that he’s speaking English. Perhaps the universal translator happens to use an English accent for someone speaking Arabic.

Comment: @MikeScott - It's explictly stated that his accent is "British", so that shows that he's speaking English, not something else that's being translated.

Comment: Just because his accent is British, he could still be speaking another language which is being translated by the Universal Translator

Answer (score 11):

Bashir's personnel file in the non-canon *[Star Trek: Starship Creator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Starship_Creator)* game states that he was born in **London, England**.

[image]

He was also implied to have ties to London in the DS9 novel, "[Hollow Men](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hollow_Men)".

> The Centaurian Embassy took up the whole of a row of what had once been four tall, terraced town houses. Sisko and Garak materialized in a small flower garden at the front of one of the houses, at the foot of a set of wide stone steps that led up into the buildings.
>
> It was late evening in early autumn. The air was damp and smelled of leaves. Twilight. Looking out from where they stood, with the embassy behind, there was a quiet street running parallel to the row of terraces. Over the road, running left to right, was a line of trees and then a row of lamps that went along the length of the embankment. Beyond the thread of lights, Sisko could see the dark line of the river.
>
> **"Where are we now?" Garak said**, staring up at the gray wash of the sky, and then taking in the outline of grayer buildings that spread out along the far bank of the river.
>
> **"London," Sisko said.**
>
> **"I think I may have heard the doctor mention it."**
>
> **"Well, this is certainly more his part of the world."**
>
> <sub>*Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* novel, "Hollow Men", by Una McCormack</sub>

---

Bashir's place of birth was never established within canon, however, according to [his Memory Alpha page](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Julian_Bashir), DS9 writer and producer, Ronald D. Moore, said that his family's roots were "probably in England", hence his father, [Richard](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Richard_Bashir), speaking in a London accent when he appeared in the episode, "[Doctor Bashir, I Presume](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Bashir,_I_Presume_(episode))".

> "In my mind, Julian was of Sudanese (like Sid), Indian, or Pakistani extraction, but that the family's roots were probably in England, hence the accents." (AOL chat, 1997)

In the real world, there are [a large number of families of South Asian descent living in England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Asian).

Some of Bashir's hobbies are also arguably clues as to his British background. For example, he and O'Brien were regularly shown playing darts at Quark's (DS9: "[Prophet Motive](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Prophet_Motive_(episode))").

Bashir also liked to roleplay as a British secret agent -- obviously inspired by James Bond -- in Quark's holosuites (DS9: "[Our Man Bashir](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Our_Man_Bashir_(episode))").

> GARAK: I take it your character is some kind of rich dilettante with a fascination for women and weapons.
>
> BASHIR: Actually, my character is far more disreputable. I'm a spy.
>
> GARAK: A spy? And you live here?
>
> BASHIR: Yes. **I work for one of the nation states of this era, Great Britain, which is battling various other nations in what is called the Cold War.** This apartment, my clothes, weapons, even my valet were provided to me by my government.
>
> GARAK: I think I joined the wrong intelligence service.
>
> <sub>*Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* - S04E10 - "Our Man Bashir"</sub>

And he and O'Brien enjoyed taking part in holographic recreations of the [Battle of Britain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Britain) (DS9: "[Homefront](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Homefront_(episode))").

Comment: Bashir also like to roleplay the Alamo

Comment: Focus on the pattern, not the individual examples.

Comment: I can't recall O'Brien playing anything traditionally Irish, other than in the EU novels.

Comment: [They certainly play darts in Ireland](https://www.rte.ie/sport/darts/2020/1203/1182071-world-darts-championship-draw-seven-irish/), so that one works for both of them. Also, [Sisko's love of baseball](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Take_Me_Out_to_the_Holosuite_(episode)) has been repeatedly referenced on the show.

Comment: It's repeatedly mentioned that they don't play baseball on Earth in the 23rd century.

Comment: That doesn't really affect my point -- that being that the sports these characters are into are arguably clues as to their nationality. We know that's true for Sisko and O'Brien. The only one that's in doubt is Bashir, but in his case, we have several other indicators that all fit the pattern of him being British.

Comment: With Sisko we know not only nationality, but city of origin - his dad *still* runs a restaurant in New Orleans which we see several times on the show, and it's implied that he's been doing that at least since Ben was a young boy.

Comment: @Valorum I always took the Alamo battles as O'Brien's choice that Bashir went along with. After all, it's O'Brien who builds the Alamo set, irritating Keiko (and generating a snide remark from Molly about his "toy"), and he leaves it to Bashir in the last episode.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Paramount-licenced game [*Star Trek: Starship Creator*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Starship_Creator), Julian Bashir's place of birth is **London, England, Earth**.

[image]

Comment: That was a great game! I never got the hang of scripting missions though :(

Comment: @Liath - I've only seen the walkthroughs. The interface looks like it was designed by a Tiberian Bat.

Comment: True, but 20 years ago it was like you were using the Star Trek computer!